# Partial derivative under Double integral

Tags: integration, partial-derivative

I wonder if Liebnez rule has other versions or results that would help explain the equality in the picture below, or is it a totally different rule?

> double integral over area and time
> $$
> \iint \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} d t d A=\iint\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(f d A)-f \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(d A)\right] d t
> $$

[from this Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6zH3.png).

Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to math stackexchange, take a time to read this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: if you find an answer useful, you could accept it or ask for more help...

Comment: Please type mathematics in Mathjax; it looks nicer and makes your question easier to find so that it can help more people in the future :) you can learn how to do so [from this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I did it for you this time since you are new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you want to see why $$\int\int \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} dt\ dA = \int\int  \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial t}(f\ dA) - f\frac{\partial }{\partial t} (dA) \right)dt$$ but this is a consequence of the product and chain rule since,

$$\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial t}(f\ dA) - f\frac{\partial }{\partial t}(dA) \right)dt = \underbrace{\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt\ dA +f\frac{\partial  }{\partial t} (dA)\ dt}_{\mathrm{product\ rule\ and\ multiply\ by\ } dt} - f\frac{\partial }{\partial t}(dA)\ dt=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt\ dA$$